# Does there any sect exists in Islam who does not believe in grave punishments?

Tags: belief, sects, grave

Assalamu Alaikum,

Does there any sect exists in Islam who does not believe in grave punishments? I.e. torments given in Barzakh life (life between world and akhirah) to a sinner?

If such sect exists, how they reply to the Quranic verses and Sahih Hadiths that prove that punishment in grave is haqq (truth) and will be given to sinners.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah mu'tazilah deny that and quranist.

Comment: It is unlikely that a quranist will deny it. Surah 23 Verses 99-100 talk about the barzakh (purgatory)

Comment: @Faqirah you should consider posting an answer!